# About identifying the quotient group

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

Let $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ be the group of matrices with non-zero determinants, and let $H=\{I,-I\}$ be the subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ ; where $I$ denotes the identity matrix. Then what is the group $GL_2(\mathbb{R})/H$ ?

Actually I know the procedure. I have to find another group and an onto homomorphism between them such that $H$ becomes the kernel of that homomorphism. But I don't have any idea how to find such group OR homomorphism ?

Comment: Hint: $A\in{}GL_2(\mathbb{R})/H$ means that $A=A'H$ which means $A=\pm{}A'$. So you have to identify $A'$ and $-A'$...

Comment: I don't really understand the question. By definition, ${\rm GL}_2({\mathbb R})/H$ is the quotient group whose elements are the cosets of $H$ in ${\rm GL}_2({\mathbb R})$.

Comment: I think OP is asking for a more familiar group to which this group will be isomorphic to.

Comment: But there is no particular reason why there should be such a more familiar group, so there is no reason to expect the question to have an answer.

Comment: @DerekHolt I agree with you on that. I was just trying to figure out "possible" expectation.